# E-Ink/E-Paper device with offline RSS reader

Tags: e-reader

I'm looking for a Kindle-style reader device which supports offline RSS reading, either built-in or via a third-party app. It would ideally be a standard RSS reader app running on the device directly, but failing that, it could be a cloud-based solution that would push regular digests/periodicals to the device. I wouldn't want anything requiring cables and syncing to a PC.

I'm surprised that I've been able to find a single app or service for any such device, but maybe I overlooked one in my research.

Comment: Have you seen this web-app for kindle (works with other devices as well) called http://www.reabble.com? It seems like it would be what you be looking for, but it may not be ideal. It isn't a native application, and it does carry a fee if you want the full-fledged application. Free users do get 15 articles a day, so you can try it out and decide if a dollar a month is worth it!

Comment: Thanks - the fee is fine, but really want it to work offline.